# It looks like changing state in child component causes App to rerender, I don't want this to happen

Tags: reactjs

I didn't pass any props from App to child component but when I change the state of the child, App rerenders( i wrote console.log('App rerendered') on App.js). Is this normal?
Can i prevent this?

Comment: Without the relevant code, it is unlikely that anyone can provide a concrete answer that's guaranteed to address your issue.

Comment: It is a reasonable general question about a general react problem, although it is almost certainly duplicating something. Probably better for a chat somewhere.